# fragment constructor has mulitple parameters

Tags: android-fragments, androidx

Error message on the console is

```
e: D:\...\Dashboard.kt: (53, 28): Too many arguments for public constructor Fragment() defined in androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
```

My dashboard fragment is

```
class Dashboard : Fragment(R.layout.dashboard1), ExportListener, SavePriorityList{
....
}
```

on the above line, it shows an error.

Does anyone also has the same issue.

Android studio version: 4.1.2
kotlin_version = "1.4.30"
sdk : 30

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution myself.

One of the libraries from Gradle uses the android - support - v4 library which causes the issue. I have removed that library from Gradle and now it's working.